# Retrieving POST request data on main view using Flask

Tags: python, post, flask, request

I have the following code in my html file

```
    <form role="form" class="animate" data-animate="fadeInUp" method="post" action="{{ url_for('test') }}">
        <div class="input-group">

            <div id="the-basics">
                <input id="search" type="text" class="typeahead form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search">
            </div>

            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
```

But when I try to get the values on my view.py, I get:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    print request.form
    print request.data
    return 'OK'

>> ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

Any clues on why I can't print the value wrote on the input box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add a name attribute to your input tag. Like this:

```
<input name="search" id="search" type="text" class="typeahead form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search">
```

That request.form object that you're trying to print is actually a dictionary. It contains values from the form, sorted by the name attributes. To retrieve the value that was in the search box, you need to access the search value inside the dictionary:

```
request.form['search']
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Sure it did. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try this `print(request.form.get("search"))`